# Equality of sets by means of a property

Tags: elementary-set-theory, definition

I have a question concerning sets. A professor said in class that the set of all prime numbers $p$ and $q$ such that $p=q$ is, in fact, the prime numbers themselves. He defined the set as follows:

$$X=\{p, q \in \mathbb{P} \; | \; p=q \}$$

Where $\mathbb{P}$ is the set of all prime numbers. And then concluded the above sentence, i. e., $X$ is equal to $\mathbb{P}$. But I just could not understand why this is the case...

In fact, I tried to prove using the definition of set equality, but all I could get was to show that if $p=q$, then $X=\{p \in \mathbb{P}\}$. And I don't even know if this is correct.

I must surely appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: You have to rewrite $X$ as $\{ p \mid p \in P \land \exists q (p=q) \}$

Comment: I've never seen the notation used in the first line.  Ordinarily in set-builder notation we have on the left a single element of the set described at a time.  A related notation that I have actually seen with a different nuance would be $X = \{(p,q)\mid p,q\in\Bbb P,~p=q\}$.  This set will consist of ordered pairs, each pair having both entries equal to the same prime.  There is going to be an obvious bijection between the set of primes and this set, simply taking $p\mapsto (p,p)$ and vice versa, but the elements themselves are of different structures so I wouldn't call them equal.

Comment: Obviously, the property $p=q$ holds iff they are the same number.  Thus, what are the numbers belonging to P for which the formula $p=q$ outputs TRUE ? The primes themselves..

Comment: hasn't the teacher rather defined the set of equivalence classes on P with identity playing the role of the partinioning relaton? I mean , hasn't he defined the set af all singleton sets having as element a prime number? In that case , the set defined would not be the set of prime numbers.

Comment: What he wrote is nonsense.

Comment: It was a Calculus class... He was defining sets by means of a property, as an intro to functions, etc... This was one example he gave...

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, the first comment is exactly what he wanted to say! I saw in my notes that he defined a two element set by a property, i. e., a set whose two elements satisfy a given property. Then he showed that is possible to extend this definition exactly how you said: $X=\{p \in P \; | \; \exists \; q \in P \; \textrm{such that P}(p,q) \}$ meaning "all the elements in $P$ for which the property P holds". Because he started with a two element set that satisfy the property P, I think that in the above example he made an abuse of notation. Thank you very much for your help!